# whats the best way to upload my php files to my server?

Tags: ftp, upload

i want to upload my php files to my dedicated server, i was thinking what was the best way to do it. i know how to do it through ftp, but but i want to a php conference and people were telling me not do it through ftp, its bad for the files or something, im still a newbie to this stuff, so enough information will be good thanks!!

:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to clear up some misconceptions, using FTP is not "bad for your files". If you use it, your files will arrive at the server unaltered and in good condition. While the FTP protocol has a laundry list of issues, the main problem is that it doesn't use any encryption. As such, both your username/password as well as your files are sent across the network in cleartext.

Is this a linux server? If so, you should look into using SCP. SCP uses SSH as a transport, and chances are good that you already have an ssh server installed and running, so it wouldn't require any additional work on your part. When using SCP, all of the data in transit is encrypted, including both your credentials as well as the files you're transferring.

Depending on what client OS you're running, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) or [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) both support SCP and will provide you a nice GUI.

Comment: can i also ask you when i tried to acees my websrever from the web browser i.e www.example.com/index.php, it gives me a pop up box instead of running the php file, what could the problem be, im running plesk

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question (probably on StackOverflow as well), as it's not at all related to this topic.

Comment: THe popup question - PHP probably isn't installed on the remote servers and therefore the browser is trying to download the file... that'd be my guess. Definitely worth another question.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP is a neat client, and it's free.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is using Samba, mapping it on your local machine and just saving it like a normal file.

SFTP is also safe. Many ftp clients support this.

Personally I like the samba option as long as you lock it down it is the most convenient and appears to have the quickest response time imho.

Comment: The use of SAMBA requires the installation of software with a less than stellar security record, which has no place on an Internet facing server.

Comment: Subjective - For the time it's been around the CVE listing is reasonable. It's more secure than FTP in that authentication information is protected, and therefore perfectly reasonable to suggest to OP as an option. OP never said internet facing.